# pass and return by reference at same time in php

Tags: php

Now I'm trying to understand references in php 
in next example I try to pass $a and returned back to $b 
I expected now the $a and $b are same!

```
function &test(& $var){
     return ++$var;
}

$a = 5;

$b = &test($a);

$b = 10;

echo $a;
echo $b;
```

but they different!
I expect 1010 but I get 610 
please someone help me in that and what going on.

Comment: `$b` isn't being set as a reference to `$a` by what you're doing; so changes to `$a` won't be reflected in `$b`.... `$b` is simply a new variable where you assign the result of the call to `test()`

Comment: why ! in first example here [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php), he use same thing to return reference from class and I try to do the same here. If you can explain to me how do it right that's will be great. thanks to you ^^

Comment: You can only return variables by reference from a function; your `test()` function is returning the result  of an expression, not a variable.... you'd actually get a notice if you had errors fully enabled. Modify your function to `function &test(& $var){ ++$var;
     return $var;
}
` and then `$b` will become a reference to `$a`

Comment: I get it now, I have no words to say Mark, Really THANKS to you <3 , because that made me very confusing :D

Comment: Using "by reference" is always awkward, and sometimes risky to use in code, because it isn't always obvious what you're doing; so it's good to understand how it works, but rarely needs to be used in reality.... code readability is far more important, and "by reference" can easily be missed when reading code

Comment: and always enable full error logging when experimenting.... that's so that you'll see notices and warnings

Comment: yes I know, but like you said .. you need to know how thing works and after that you can use them wisely, and I'll remember your words always ^^ <3.